# Practical bit operations that save hours of work

Tags: algorithm, logic

I am wondering what other bitwise and logical operations you've used that saved your day.

For example, my last great time (and resources') saver has been

```
if(!((A^B) & B))
```

reads: *if A has at least B's access rights*, where rights were saved in the bit fields A and B.

Please use the classical operators: binary & (and) | (or), ^ (xor), ~ (invert)
and the logical ones && (and), || (or), ! (not).

Comment: Are you aware that your example is equivalent to `if (!(~A & B))`?

Comment: Now that you ask, yes. But that was the result of the naive translation from my cognitive processes to logic :-) Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Nothing wrong with your way of doing it though -- even in the unlikely event that this is very time-critical, both approaches use the same number of operations anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mandatory link: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html.

Comment: Love that page! I originally found it looking for a quick way to get the integer part of the log (base 2) of an integer

Answer (score -1):

double negation rules: `!! value` result in 1 or 0.